# list of lists to standard Python array.array, not NumPy

Tags: python, arrays

I want to convert a list of lists to a standard Python array.array. Let's take good ol' [[1.0, 2.0][3.0, 4.0]] as an example. Answers to similar Q seem to all be in terms of NumPy. I am doing something to be used by folks who are very unlikely to import numpy.

Comment: `array.array` arrays are 1-dimensional.

Comment: "I want to" - Why?

Comment: Hey @Kirke welcome to Stack. Your question is quite vague in what you need answered ... check this post on the proper way to ask a question https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible, as `array.array` arrays are 1-dimensional. You can't even make a nested array, as `array.array` arrays only hold primitives.

You should probably read the [`array` module docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html) and think about whether `array.array` arrays are actually suitable for your use case, as you seem to be expecting more NumPy-like behavior from them than they actually provide.